# Binomial GLMM model that fails to converge: which random effect to remove?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, logit, convergence, glmm

I am trying to use a binomial generalized linear mixed model to analyze binary data of an experiment. Just few details on the experiment that could be useful:

- The dependent variable is `Score`: 0 (incorrect); 1 (correct)
- The two predictors are `CongRec`: -1 (Congruent); +1 (Incongruent) and
  `TempsExp`: 6 levels (33ms,50ms,67ms,..117ms), used as a categorical
  predictor.

For each combination of the levels of the two predictors, we have 40 observations for 29 participants.

**The issue**: When I try to fit a model with only the main effects of the predictors (+intercept) and by-subject random slope for both `Congruency` and `ExposureTime`, the model fails to converge.

In such cases, I have been told to remove the random effect with the smallest variance. However depending on the way I define the predictor `Congruence`, i.e., as a categorical predictor with 2 levels (`Congruence`) or as continuous variable (`CongRec`), the random effect with the smallest variance differs.

Here is the R command for the (second) model:

```
Model4_Categbis = glmer(formula = Score~1+CongRec+TempsExp+(1+CongRec+TempsExp|Sujet), 
                        data=donneestestCN, family="binomial", REML=F)
```

Here are the random effects for both cases:

1. `Congruency` as categorical predictor

   [image]
2. `Congruency` as continuous predictor

   [image]

So basically, in the first case, I should remove the random slope for `CongRec` while, in the second case, I should remove the random intercept by subject. Normally, I think the way I define the predictor `Congruence` should not have any influence on model main characteristics but, here, it does because of the non-convergence.

So, which random effects should I remove in your opinion and, that being done, which type of variable should I use for Congruency?